# Can I add an invitee to an Outlook meeting another person created?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, meetings

I've been invited to a meeting - I am not the organizer.  Is there any way for me to add another attendee, other than out-of-band communication?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open your appointment in Calendar (double-click on appointment) and then click on Forward.
You can forward the invite to your collegues; the message will be in this form:

**Header:** "YourName" on behalf of "OrganizerName"

**Cc:** Organizer of invitation

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the above, when you on the forward option, there should be a dropdown menu, with a further option (forward as icalendar), this will forward the attachment as a calendar so the To... Recipients can open it and click accept. In my opinion, it is simpler to create a new meeting and invite people that way, unless you provide instructions telling people to open the calendar attachment and then to accept the invite.